# RecyclerView - Getting adapter position in ItemDecoration's onDraw method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In itemDecoration's on draw method it has a override method called getItemOffsets which I can get the adapter's position using:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
}
```

How ever if I try this method inside onDraw:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
      int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(   ???   );
}
```

What do I pass for the view parameters?

Comment: Have you tried parent.getFocusedChild() as parameter??

Comment: @Naitik it returns -1 each time

Comment: Can I know why you want position in onDraw() ? @david

Comment: @Naitik In my SimpleDivider class I have a constructor that takes an ArrayList<Int> I want to get the position of the Adapter using parent.getChildAdapterPosition so I could use that position to get the index of my ArrayList. Once I have that index value, I use it to draw a divider a certain amount of times.

Comment: So far it works in getItemOffSets method. I can successfully draw a certain amount of spacing based on my ArrayList value. But I can't seem to get it to work in onDraw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onDraw()` You are working on one canvas. To modify one child, You have to iterate by all the parent's children.

```
int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
    View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
    int childAdapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    // ...
}
```